# Element not getting deleted even after I have used even delegation

Tags: html

I made this form using jQuery.

[image]

The jQuery code which I wrote to add this is as follows :

```
formView:function(){
        var htmlStr = '<form><input class = "name"/><input class = "imageUrl"/><input class = "counter"/></form><button class="cancel">Cancel</button>'
        $('#form').html(htmlStr);
        // octopus.changeFlag();
    }
```

and the code to collapse this form, I used jQuery as event delegation as below :

```
$('#form').on('click','cancel',function(e){
            console.log("Hello world");
            $('#form').html('');
            // e.preventDefault();
        });
```

My HTML code is as below:

```
<body>
<ul class = "list">
</ul>
<img class="image" src="images/Vaibhav.jpg">
<div id="count"></div>
<div id="admin">
    <button class="admin">Admin</button>
    <div id = "form"></div>
</div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Whenever I click on cancel, it should collapse the form, but its not happening. Thanks in advance.

p.s. I am a beginner to jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.` to your selector for class `cancel`

```
$('#form').on('click','.cancel',function(e){
    console.log("Hello world");
    $('#form').remove();
    // e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and I am surely gonna get too many negatives on this question. :P But seriously I was wandering for last 2 hours for this little typo.

Comment: @AjayGaur It's an honest mistake. I dont think anyone's gonna downvote